I am using MailChimp to write a news letter and I have a space under the image in mobile view
I am making a newsletter in mailchimp and having a problem with a white space under my image. I fixed it in desktop mode but the space is still there in mobile mode, how do I get rid of it if I'm limited to an HTML textbox?
Here's the code:
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <img src="imagine there's a link here" alt="crane image" style="vertical-align: bottom;" width="100%" height="100%">
</p>

I tried absbottom as well, but it didn't work.

Have you tried setting the margin and padding to 0 on the image, if not also try to display: block on the image style. The display change to block makes the image occupy the container fully hopefully removing white margins around it.
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="imagine there's a link here" alt="crane image" style="vertical-align: bottom; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" width="100%" height="100%"></p>

try without the display: block first to see if it works.

i'll give it a go but yeah padding is 0 on top and bottom only exists on sides so that it doesn't look weird on mobile
